# jQuery live handler but for each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I know that `live()` can be used to support event handlers for current AND "added later" DOM elements.

I wonder how to do the same thing with `each()`?

Like if I have `$('.something_or_other').each()` but then another DOM element with `class="something_or_other"` gets added? How can I set it up to automatically apply the each iteration to this new DOM element?

OR, what can I call after adding the new DOM element to reapply the `each()` rules.

(Showing my age a bit here but in Behaviour we can use `Behaviour.apply()` to reapply ALL of the rules!)

Comment: Sounds like you want to just create an initial jquery object jqObj = $(selector) and have future matches to the selector added to the object's array? I think we need more information about what you're trying to do, and why it's not acceptable to create a new jquery object after you've added your new DOM element.

Comment: I am using jQuery to "autocompleterise" text inputs with class="autocompleter". Now, some of these autocompleters have an "onValueAccepted" callback which is to dynamically insert ANOTHER autocompleter text input underneath itself.

Comment: jQuery already has an amazing autocomplete UI widget, take a look. You may not need to write your code. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/. If that doesn't work for you, you can extend it to work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **@meder** noted, you should really just do this manually. You can use the same function for both if you like.

```
function myFunction(i,val) {
    $(this).doSomething;
}

$('someSelector').each( myFunction );

$.ajax({
    url:'/some/path/',
    success: function( data ) {
        $(data).find('someSelector').each( myFunction )
               .end().appendTo('body');
    }
});
```

---

If you *really* don't want to do that, there's a plugin called `livequery` that will run code when an element that matches a selector is added to (or removed from) the DOM.

It costs a bit of extra overhead, but it is an option.

http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs

Comment: livequery looks like what I was thinking. Thanks. Other people's points are also very valid.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just bind the functionality to the ajax callback that appends the DOM elements to the doc? Seems the shortest and most logical route to me.

Comment: What functionality! I'm hoping that there's an automatic way to do it. But also I would like to know how I could do it manually. Do I have to repeat all of the code in the each() iteration specifically for the new added element??!??